# Who owns the rights to code I contribute to a gpled open source project while at work?

Tags: contracts

When I was hired as an intern, I signed all sorts of paperwork (which I'm told isn't legally binding anyway because I'm a minor), some of which was about "inventions"; inventions I had made that I would use at work, and that anything I "invented" at work is the property of the company.

Having seen some other questions asked here, I know this means that any code I write for the company isn't mine. What about code I write for an open source project licensed with GPL? Is THAT the company's property? Hypothetically, what if the code was used in the project and became a staple in its structure and then a couple years later the company realizes what happens and claims the rights to that code?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but my understanding of the GPL is it protects that code, and anything else added to it is automatically covered by the GPL. The exception is a library licensed under the LGPL in your product, the library license has no effect on the proprietary product the library is used in. With the Apache 2.0 License, you can do whatever you want with the code, including not re-releasing updates, meaning that it's up to the company what to do with it.

Comment: This question cannot be effectively answered without the following information: Was your work on GPL code approved by your supervisor/manager? Was the GPL'ed code incorporated into a software product which was distributed to third parties? Was that software product distributed under the GPL? Remember, on stack exchange, it is better to edit your question than post a comment with this information.

Comment: My biggest concern is that you were writing open source code while at work. If your supervisor did not approve of that prior to doing so, that is a firing offense.

Comment: @HLGEM - I started writing an answer based on that very point, but I realised that there were too many unknowns in this question and I had too many nested if then else's in my answer. Hence asking for more information. I don't think any of the current answers are useful because non of them (can) get to the root of the problem.

Comment: is the gpl code you wrote used in any of your company's products?

Comment: @Rarity - Could this be moved to Programmers.SE (assuming, perhaps, that the question is, in general, improved upon with more info)? It seems that it would be on topic there, if it's not on topic here (though, why is it considered off topic here?).

Comment: Legal stuff: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq#what-questions-are-off-topic-here I'll ask programmers, but I don't think they like legal questions either. Update: nope

Comment: “Inventions” in this context means patents, not works covered by copyright such as code. The code you write at work usually belongs to the company, there's probably a clause for that in your paperwork as well, or that may be the legal default where you work. If the project is covered by GPL, everyone else (including you) may reuse it under the terms of the GPL.

Comment: @walkerneo - You should seek legal advice if the contract you signed is actually valid or not, the fact you are a minor but working for a coperation for pay,  which means your legal obligations might have been passed down to your parents even if they didn't sign said paperwork.

Comment: @giles uh not in some countrys (the UK for example)  if you do things outside of work that are related to your job - the employer owns it.

You would need to check a the contract and your country employment laws.

Comment: This depends totally on the state you live in. In many, the code belongs to the employer - not you. In the absence of contracts otherwise, most courts hold that you are performing "work for hire" and the copyrights belong to your employer and never revert to you.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/74105/is-it-legal-for-me-to-contribute-to-open-source-software-while-employed/74120#74120

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a lawyer either and I don't think the law is the most important part of the question even though it is what you asked about.

Two things to consider:

1. Your company believes that everything you do on their property/equipment/time (or whatever you signed) is their intellectual property.  Being a company, they presumably have a lawyer.  I don't think they would go after you being a minor and this likely not being an important piece of code in their eyes.
2. You are just starting out in your career.  You want a positive reference and goodwill.  Going against a company's policy isn't a great way to do that.

Comment: Jeanne in some places its not "believe" they do own related IP

Comment: @Neuro agreed.  Some employers have you sign everything is theirs.  I was trying to generalize.

Comment: well if your contract in the UK is silent this the default but it does have to be "related" though the General Consul (now a senior member of BT's HR team) that explained it to me said it can be quite broad and most employees don't have the resources to fight a court case over.

Answer (score -2):

Not being a lawyer, I can't really say who is strictly bound to what.  For information like that you'll need to consult an actual lawyer.  Generally speaking, however, the company cannot assert ownership over code that the company (or an agent of the company) publishes under the GPL.

The GPL is like a cancer.  Any code that comes in contact with GPL'ed code becomes GPL'ed itself.  So the long and the short of it is that the company *cannot* "claim the rights" to code that it has previously published under GPL.  They lost that ability as soon as the code was released under the GPL.

To answer your hypothetical, if the GPL'ed code was integrated into some larger, proprietary codebase, then the company is technically obligated to release the *entire* proprietary codebase under the GPL.  It doesn't matter how much the company relies upon the proprietary codebase, or whether or not the company knowingly incorporated the GPL'ed code into their project.  Once the GPL code was added to the codebase, the entire codebase became GPL'ed.  Like I said, it's like a cancer.

This is why many technology companies have very strict policies governing the use of GPL'ed code.  Many companies will only allow a GPL library to be used as part of a project if the GPL code is confined to its own process.  Some companies will not even allow that.

So no matter what documents have been signed, and whether or not they are enforceable, the company cannot "reclaim" code released under the GPL.  What they can do, however, is fire anyone they catch releasing proprietary code under an open-source license, or incorporating GPL code into a proprietary codebase.  You should really get permission from the company before doing either of those things.

Comment: -1, yes GPL spread to the whole project, but one isn't "obligated to release the etiere proprierary codebase". One may just remove the GPL part, and move on. Also company can reclaim code released under GPL if the OP wasn't allowed to realease it, as the right might belong to the company they are working in.

Comment: @ClementHerreman - One is obligated to release the entire codebase if one intends to keep using the GPL'ed bit.  And that intent is a reasonable assumption given the question, which concerns the consequences of mixing GPL and proprietary code.  But if you want to split hairs over the fact that if one does _not_ intend to use GPL'ed code then you don't have to release your code, then be my guest.  I consider that distinction obvious to the point of being self-evident.  The question was about what happens when you _do_ use the code.